# Create Element Function at higher level in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a hook for a personal project which allows me to create a popup div at mouse coordinates when `onClick` is triggered. That div will be defined in a variable seperate from it's parent component's return statement.

Is there a function in React that allows me to create a **new** element at the app level? *I need to be able to create a new element at a different position than where the function is called.* The div will be removed from the DOM when the user clicks outside of it. I've looked into `React.createElement`, but it doesn't seem to serve this purpose.

I know I could probably use vanilla functions for this, but I was wondering if there's a better React way of doing it.